# Sublime Text Xdebug won't stop at breakpoints

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

I have a full installation of Xdebug on my PHP local install, but when I try to run Xdebug inside of my Sublime Text project, for some reason it does not recognise any of the breakpoints. I have tried many things so far to get this to work.

- Xdebug client installed.
- Project File

```
 {
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks":true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "xdebug":
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:9312/simplephp/"
        }
    }
}
```

php.ini:

```
[xdebug]

zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.force_display_errors=on
xdebug.force_error_reporting=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9312
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_log="/c/wamp64/www/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

Chrome Xdebug extension enabled.

Tried changing the port, looking for instances that are blocking the port etc, but found none.

Also nothing is currently being written to the log (which is an empty txt file).

Any suggestions would be brilliant.

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_log="/c/wamp64/www/xdebug/xdebug.log"` -- always use proper Windows path (`C:\ ....`) 2) Will it do/write into a log anything if you add `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code that is executed for sure? 3) Please try that in some very simple file (e.g. <?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo "$c\n"; -- every statement on it's own line) 4) Share WHOLE Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output captured in the same way you are trying to debug it (as your setup may have different configs for CLI and web based debug).

Comment: 5) `"url": "http://localhost:9312/simplephp/"` and this `xdebug.remote_port=9312` -- ??? Why is Xdebug port used in BOTH? Please check how Xdebug works (it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around) and that Xdebug port is a completely DIFFERENT thing than your web server port / script URL. **P.S.** I'm not a Sublime Text user myself (another IDE user) so cannot advice on anything ST-specific, only Xdebug/PHP debug overall (which is the same approach regardless of the IDE/editor anyway).

Comment: Hi @LazyOne, thanks for the tips, that's all well and good and I've been able to get xdebug going and stopping at breakpoints when using my local (wamp) server. I think it was the port that fixed it. However when I work on my Laravel projects I like to use 'php artisan serve' which boots a separate php server that runs on 'localhost:8000'. For some reason, XDebug is not installed on here, even though it's present on my Wamp. Any ideas on how I can install this (can I require it with composer?). I'm using composer and artisan commands on a Windows server. Thx :)

Comment: Run `php -i` in command line (it is the same as calling `phpinfo()`) and check 1) what config files are used (they may be different to what WAMP uses) 2) If Xdebug is present and how it's configured. If any differences: apply the same config here as well. P.S. You can run `where php` to see what the actual PHP executable is: maybe it;s not a WAMP one etc

Comment: Yup, I've noticed there are two different php.ini files in my wamp, C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini and C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0\php.ini. The settings for xdebug were only present in the first one. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Consider posting your findings as an answer: it will help others in similar situation (answered question has better visibility etc). You can accept own answer after some delay (an hour or so I believe).